# XSL Placing End Tags After Loop

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm having an issue with this XSL file that I can only reproduce on my server environment and not on any online testing tools.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>

<xsl:template match="Contest">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@title = 'MAYOR'">
            <article class="results-cumulative mayor" id="mayoral-candidates">
                <h2>Mayoral Candidates</h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="Candidate">
                    <div class="row candidate-single">
                        <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
                            <h3><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
                            <div class="data-bar">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </article>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Not Supported
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- do nothing for unmatched text or attribute nodes -->
<xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Owner xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/C:/ELEC.xsd" id="2014">
    <ReportTime>2014-10-14T14:41:03Z</ReportTime>
    <Election id="0" electionName="ELEC1" electionTitle="" final="1" totalBallotsCast="65" totalRegistration="0" totalCastPercentage="00.0" reportedRegistration="0" reportedPercentage="00.0" totalPrecincts="55" precinctsReported="12" precinctsReportedPercentage="21.82">
        <ContestList>
            <Contest id="101" altId2="100001" partyId="1" stateWide="1" title="MAYOR" typeCode="" voteFor="1" runoff="0" ballotsCast="65" castPercentage="00.0" writeinVotes="0" overVotes="0" underVotes="15">
                <Candidate id="1" altId2="1000001" pos="1" name="NAME" partyId="1" winner="1" runoff="0" recount="0">
                </Candidate>
                <Candidate id="2" altId2="1000002" pos="2" name="NAME" partyId="1" winner="1" runoff="0" recount="0">
                </Candidate>
                <Candidate id="3" altId2="1000003" pos="3" name="NAME" partyId="1" winner="1" runoff="0" recount="0">
                </Candidate>
            </Contest>
        </ContestList>
    </Election>
</Owner>
```

The expected output I want to receive would be as follows:

```
<article class="results-cumulative mayor" id="mayoral-candidates">
   <h2>Mayoral Candidates</h2>
   <div class="row candidate-single">
      <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
         <h3>NAME</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
         <div class="data-bar">
            <div class="bar"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row candidate-single">
      <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
         <h3>NAME</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
         <div class="data-bar">
            <div class="bar"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row candidate-single">
      <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
         <h3>NAME</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
         <div class="data-bar">
            <div class="bar"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

Notice, ".row .candidate-single" elements are siblings to each other. Instead I receive this:

```
<article class="results-cumulative mayor" id="mayoral-candidates">
   <h2>Mayoral Candidates</h2>
   <div class="row candidate-single">
      <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
         <h3>NAME</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
         <div class="data-bar">
            <div class="bar"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row candidate-single">
         <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
            <h3>NAME</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
            <div class="data-bar">
               <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row candidate-single">
            <div class="results-cumulative--name columns small-12 large-4">
               <h3>NAME</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="results-cumulative--votes columns small-12 large-8">
               <div class="data-bar">
                  <div class="bar"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</article>
```

The ".row .candidate-single" elements are being nested within each other and I can't figure out why this would be occurring. The server's XSL processor outputs "Microsoft" for system-property('xsl:vendor') and 12014-10-14 for system-property('xsl-version'). Any ideas?

Comment: I tested your XSLT file with your XML file and **I cannot reproduce** the error. The output is as your _expected output_ looks like. My XSLT processors are `xsltproc` and `Saxon9HE`.

Comment: If you can only reproduce on your server environment, the most obvious answer is the XSLT being run on your server environment is not the one you have shown in your question.